# Non-invocable member 'xyz' can not be used like a method, Difference between vb and c#

Tags: c#

I have this code in VB:

```
Private mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails As IEnumerable(Of 
EmpTimesheetDeclareDetail) = Nothing

If mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails.Count > 0 Then
mEmpTimesheetDeclareDetail = mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails(0)
End If
```

Now i have converted the same piece of code in c#:

```
private IEnumerable<EmpTimesheetDeclareDetail> mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails = null;

if (mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails.Count() > 0)
{
  mEmpTimesheetDeclareDetail = (EmpTimesheetDeclareDetail)mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails(0);
}
```

It gives me error here `(EmpTimesheetDeclareDetail)mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails(0)` Non-invocable member can not be used like a method. Though i understand the error that i am using `mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails` as a method which is incorrect. But how does it accepts it in VB? and how can i achieve this in c#?

Comment: You can also do `mEmpTimesheetDeclareDetail = mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails.ElementAt(0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared your member as an `IEnumerable<T>`. An `IEnumerable<T>` does not support indexing, as it's a sequence of values. You're looking for `ElementAt()`. So, your code would become:

```
mEmpTimesheetDeclareDetail = mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails.ElementAt(0);
```

Note that you don't need to cast the result, as the result of `ElementOf()` will be the same as `T` (in this case, since you're written `IEnumerable<EmpTimesheetDeclareDetail>`, the result will be `EmpTimesheetDeclareDetail`).

In addition, there's a few other things you can tidy up:

Use `.Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`. Depending on where your sequence comes from, this can prevent the entire sequence from being materialised, it'll only materialise the first item to check if the sequence is not empty.

Also, there exists `First` and `FirstOrDefault()` which are a bit clearer than `ElementAt(0)`. The former will throw an exception if there are no elements, the latter will return `null` in your case. However, since you've already checked there are elements, `First()` is more suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

`mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails(0)` should be `mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails.ElementAt(0)`

In `c#` index should be accessed through a pair of square brackets `[]`. here Brackets are for calling methods. So when you use `mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails(0)`, the compiler assumes that you are calling a method named `mTemmpEmpTimesheetDeclareDetails` with an integer parameter.

But in your case you are accessing an `IEnumerable<T>` based on its index, so you have to use the method `.ElementAt(index)`, Because Enumerable is more generic, and a collection represented by enumerable may not have an indexer

Comment: No. i tried that, it gives me an error saying cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IEnumerable<EmpTimesheetDeclareDetail>